# Spring container implementations

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I keep on learning Spring and it is very difficult to figure out which implementation of `ApplicationContext` is intended for. I've standalone J2EE application and I don't interested in Web* or Portlet* implementations.

*Can you provide me the brief list of possibilities (if isn't clear, see P.S. section of my question) and purposes of each implementation below:*

- `ResourceAdapterApplicationContext`
- `StaticApplicationContext`
- `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`
- `FileSystemApplicationContext`

***P.S.***

A don't ask you to provide me reference to the docs. For example:

> ClassPathXmlApplicationContext Standalone XML application context,
>   taking the context definition files from the class path, interpreting
>   plain paths as class path resource names that include the package path

But from that definition its not clear that `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` also implements `AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext` and can be used to change beans definition without stopping server.

Comment: *Standalone JEE* application means Swing?

Comment: No. Java + Spring IoC + communication via Websockets + Backbone.js to handle routing on client side.

Comment: I am confused with the sentence *"I am not interested in **WEB** or Portlet implementations"*. Are you using Servlet API or you are working with web sockets directly?

Comment: I'm working with WebSockets directly

Comment: I know JavaEE. What is JEE?

Comment: @IndoKnight Yes, I mean JavaEE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry you don't want references to the docs, but that's where all the information is.

`StaticApplicationContext` states

> `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` implementation which
>   supports programmatic  registration of beans and messages, rather than
>   reading bean definitions from external onfiguration  sources. Mainly
>   useful for testing.

So you use it to register bean definitions directly

```
StaticApplicationContext context = new StaticApplicationContext();
context.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefinition);
```

This can be used in cases where your `ApplicationContext` needs to be dynamically changed. Note that you can pass a parent `ApplicationContext` to the `StaticApplicationContext` if you need both behaviors, ie. reading from XML/Java config and dynamically registering.

---

`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` is one of the more common `ApplicationContext` implementations in my opinion. You simply point it to an XML (bean definition) resource on the classpath and it loads it up. The javadoc states

> Useful for test harnesses as well as for application contexts embedded
>   within JARs.

You could therefore simply point to a resource on the classpath coming from a JAR and load that. It's simply enough to setup tests environments this way.

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("some-context.xml");
// boom you're ready to go
```

Note that Spring's JUnit support classes offer other (better) ways to setup testing environment.

> But from that definition its not clear that
>   `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` also implements
>   `AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext` and can be used to change beans
>   definition without stopping server.

That's what the javadoc is for.

---

`FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` is similar to the `ClasspathXmlApplicationContext` above, but it takes the configuration files from the file system instead of reading resources from the classpath.

---

`ResourceAdapterApplicationContext` states

> `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` implementation for a
>   JCA `ResourceAdapter`. Needs to be initialized with the JCA
>   `javax.resource.spi.BootstrapContext`, passing it on to Spring-managed
>   beans that  implement `BootstrapContextAware`.

I haven't worked with this one at all and I don't know where Resource Adapters are useful, but [here are some more docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23717_01/doc.71/e23701/dev_jca_adapter.htm).

Comment: Does that implementations have another interesting abbilities? (like dynamic config refresh) If yes, just re-count them. I ask because I found none.

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk I don't understand your question. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: Yes I mean that `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` both implements `AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext` and can dynamically add bean definitions. As for me it's very interesting (and in some cases useful) abbility. So I jusk asking if there are another such abilities in those 4 container implementations.

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk If you have an IDE, open up the class you are interested in (you will need the source code) and look up the type hierarchy. You can see all the super types. Each type inherited provides its own set of functionality. There's too much to go over in an answer here.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add couple things to @Solitirios answer:

You forgot to mention several more context:

- **GenericApplicationContext**
- **GenericXmlApplicationContext**
- **AnnotationConfigApplicationContext**
- **GenericWebApplicationContext**
- **StaticWebApplicationContext**

And many others.

In general, `GenericApplicationContext` is almost the same as `StaticApplicationContext`, the only difference between them in `MessageSource` support in `StaticApplicationContext`. Purpose for both of these classes is for small tests with tiny application context with couple beans.

`GenericWebApplicationContext` and `StaticWebApplicationContext` are also quite similar to each other, and typically they are used for emulation of Servlet container, e.g. tests or non-Servlet environment.

F.e. you can use something like this in your code (f.e. tests):

```
//create parent context
ApplicationContext xmlContext = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/spring-*.xml");
//create mock servlet context
MockServletContext mockServletContext = new MockServletContext();
//create web context
GenericWebApplicationContext webContext = new GenericWebApplicationContext(mockServletContext);
//set attribute
mockServletContext.setAttribute(GenericWebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, webContext);
//set parent context
webContext.setParent(xmlContext);
//refresh context
webContext.refresh();
```

But there are couple contexts classes, which are worthy of attention. And considering your pre-requisites, I would choose one of them.

[GenericXmlApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericXmlApplicationContext.html) is very good alternative of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`. Consider this example:

```
ApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("classpath:some-context.xml");
```

is equivalent to

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("some-context.xml");
```

or

```
ApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("some-context.xml");
```

is equivalent to

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("some-context.xml");
```

So `GenericXmlApplicationContext` looks more flexible.

[AnnotationConfigApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html) is a context holder, if you don't want to keep your beans in XML-file.

```
//context creation
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);

//context class
    @Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.examples.services")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSources dataSource() {
        DataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();

        //... init ds

        return ds;
    }

}
```

More information you can find [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html).

Comment: thanks! And what is the difference between `GenericApplicationContext` and `StaticApplicationContext`

Comment: you said that Generic (Static) -WebApplicationContext are using to emulate Servlet container, e.g. non-Servlet environment. For what someone will want to do that. Explain that, please